# What is "traits allow composition"?

Tags: scala, composition, traits

I'm reading the first section of the book "Scala in depth". In the first section, it gives an example which convert a java JdbcTemplate interface to scala:

Java code:

```
public interface JdbcTemplate {
  List query(PreparedStatementCreator psc,
    RowMapper rowMapper)
}
```

Scala code:

```
trait JdbcTemplate {
  def query[ResultItem](psc : Connection => PreparedStatement,
                        rowMapper : (ResultSet, Int) => ResultItem) : List[ResultItem]
￼}
```

Then it says:

> With a few simple transformations, we've created an interface that works directly against functions. This is a more functional approach simply because scala's function traits allow composition. By the time you're finished reading this book, you'll be able to approach the design of this interface completely differently.

I can't understand "traits allow composition" here, since I can't find any "composition" in the example provided.

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Maybe the example does not use composition, but allows for composition.

Comment: I guess they mean trait mix-in composition

Comment: Maybe the word "this is" should be "there is"?

Answer (score 3):

You've missed the first part of this phrase:

> scala's function traits allow composition

In scala function is a simple object constructed from a trait like `Function[-T, +R]` and on all such traits you have two methods: `andThen` and `compose`.

Comment: Interesting, but still not clear. If you can provide an example with the given code in the question, that will be great

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet **is not** a compositon sample but **would allow** for composition. Indeed, a `trait` alone composed nothing more than..itself with itself :)

Trait allows to compose at runtime thanks to the `with`keyword.
Basically, it allows to add trait's methods to associated `trait` or `class` or even...runtime object!
Composition is known to be a runtime feature (its major benefit) and inheritance is known to be a compilation feature, thus static.

Here's a sample using `trait` composition at runtime:

```
val obj1 = new MyClass() with JdbcTemplate
//obj1.query .......
```

Compared to Java, if `MySuperClass` was a `class` or `abstract class`, you could still add/alter behaviour from elsewhere at runtime by implementing some kind of Strategy pattern etc... but it would require you to describe an interface + implementation..boring.
On the contrary, `Trait` allows to define method in one place.

That's why in scala, `trait` is said to "allow composition", and obviously, functional programming concept fit better with composition rather than inheritance.

**UPDATE ----------------------**

@Alexlv is right => the important word was Scala's **FUNCTION** traits. 
My above explanation still right, but doesn't correspond to what the author wanted to mean.
IMHO, he wanted to mean: `Connection => PreparedStatement` is a `Function1`, and as functions are fond of composition, it enables some nice processing providing from the functional programming word to generate the required `query` method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The point the author is making is that replacing `PreparedStatementCreator` and `RowMapper` with function types yields a more functional API (surprise!). The API better supports code reuse since the `psc` and `rowMapper` functions can be composed from simple functional components. You might have functions, for example, that `filter` the `ResultSet`, extract various pieces of data, transform the data (`map`), aggregate it (`fold`), etc.

As @Alexiv pointed out, all Scala function objects (via the various `Function` traits) provide `andThen` and `compose` methods that support function composition.